# req.file in multer always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

My code below

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

Below is the config for the multer.

```
const multer = require("multer");

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/'});
```

Edit:1.
Also tried this configuration instead of the direct upload variable.But this doesnt work either.

```
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "/image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

Product add form processing.
Here i am processing the form and console.log always returns undefined.

```
router.post("/productadd", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  const newProduct = {
    imagePath: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/480*480",
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    price: req.body.price
  };

  new Products(newProduct).save().then(product => {
    res.redirect("/products");
  });
});
```

Here is my form for the file upload

```
<form action="/productadd" Method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter the Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Enter the Price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image">Choose an Image:</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You code seems to work fine I also tested it [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/szamanis/e5b31dc2557eef63e8463ed19b34075d) . can you test if this works for you too?

Comment: Yeah it works there , thanks. Seems I found the problem. Thanks for the help .